# Redirect domain name

Tags: apache-http-server, regex, mod-rewrite

I have two domain names pointing to my server.  I want them both to serve identical HTML.  I thought I would just do the following, however, it was unsuccessful.  Note that I eventually will want ssl 443 to act similarly.

How do I make any requests to mydomain.net display HTML from mydomain.com?

Thank you

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.net
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule mydomain.net mydomain.com [PT]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ...
  a bunch of stuff
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this VirtualHost configuration instead of the one in your question:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.net
  ...
  a bunch of stuff
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks Tero, but I don't believe this is an option as I have other websites hosted on the server, and need to use virtual hosts.  I know that rewriting is a possibility, but just don't know how to do it.

Comment: I meant the first VirtualHost section you had in your question. You can leave your other VirtualHosts as is. The `ServerAlias` directive makes Apache serve the same HTML content to both `mydomain.net` and `mydomain.com`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't originally understand.  So, I put `ServerAlias mydomain.net` in another the VirtualHost directory?

Comment: I have edited my answer with more clear example.

Comment: Thanks Tero,  Works perfectly.  I really didn't expect it to work as I thought I needed to rewrite, and was pleasantly surprised!